# How to print unique values of a column of DataFrame in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I create a DataFrame from Parquet file as follows:

```
DataFrame parquetFile = sqlContext.read().parquet("test_file.parquet");
parquetFile.printSchema();
parquetFile.registerTempTable("myData");
DataFrame data_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM myData");
```

Now I want to print out all unique values of a column that is called `field1`.

I know that in case of using Python, it would be possible to run `import pandas as pd` and then convert `data_df` to Pandas DataFrame, after which use `unique()`.

But how can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very straightforward, you can use the distinct function in the SQL query

```
DataFrame data_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT DISTINCT(field1) FROM myData");
```

Here's an example :

```
val myData = Seq("h", "h", "d", "b", "d").toDF("field1")
myData.createOrReplaceTempView("myData")
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
sqlContext.sql("SELECT DISTINCT(field1) FROM myData").show()
```

this gives the following output :

```
+------+                                                                        
|field1|
+------+
|     h|
|     d|
|     b|
+------+
```

Hope this help, Best Regrads

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the duplicate and get `distinct` values by

```
parquetFile.dropDuplicates("field1")
```

This gives you only `distinct` rows by `field1`

Answer (score 1):

```
DataFrame uniqueDF = data_df.groupBy("field1");
uniqueDF.show();
```

Comment: `GroupedData` cannot be shown. You probably missed `count()`:  `data_df.groupBy('field1').count().show()`